# How to initialize jsonpath in a web application

Tags: java, jsonpath

Changing the configuration defaults as demonstrated should only be done when your application is being initialized. Changes during runtime is strongly discouraged, especially in multi threaded applications.

Can someone explain how I would do that in the init method of the Servlet that is loaded on start up of the web application ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented it myself :

Create an instance as follows :

private static JsonProvider jsonProvider;

Then in the init method, initialize it as follows :

jsonProvider = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider();

You can change provider as needed.

And then use the instance in GET / POST requests.